# Why isn't there any movement on the crude Palm Oil futures market?

Tags: futures, commodities

I am trying to understand why it seems so hard to trade futures contracts of crude palm oil. I know the largest futures for it is in Malaysia, but apparently the CME also carries it under the symbol FCPO. However, I can't seem to get it... I went to my interactive brokers account and there is no underlying futures under "FCPO". Also, if I go to the CME group futures contract detail (https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/grain-and-oilseed/usd-malaysian-crude-palm-oil-calendar.html), I see absolute nothing! There's no reported last price, ask, bid, volume, nothing!! The charts look really weird as well, as if there was no liquidity whatsoever.

How can I trade crude palm oil futures?

Comment: "*Contact a broker in a country where people care about **crude** palm oil*" is probably the best answer.

Comment: the list of participating brokers is at http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/derivatives/brokers/list-of-trading-participants/ and it appears that there are subsidiaries of several western banks on the list so they might be worth asking.

Answer (score 2):

Many exchanges create contracts in the hope that one day someone might trade them. Until someone does, there are no prices.

All the palm oil futures trading happens in Malaysia, and there is no compelling reason (so far) for anyone to trade it on the CME instead. Remember that, even if the monetary terms might be identical, the contracts on the two exchanges are NOT fungible.

If you want to trade palm oil futures in Malaysia, find a broker that offers that service.